# css menu not clickable (in mobile)

Tags: html, css, button, mobile, menu

It's probably something easy I missed, but I'm making a regular menu for mobile devices and for some reason it doesn't work. All help welcome! I'm not very good at this :( if you prefer I can give you an online link.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>title</title>
<!--fonts--!>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="back">
  <div id="top"><logo><a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a></logo> 
  <menu>
  <div class="button1"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
  <div class="button2"><a href="#">button1</a></div>
  <div class="button3"><a href="#">button2</a></div>
  <div class="button4"><a href="#">button3</a></div>
  <div class="button5"><a href="#">button4</a></div>
  <div class="button6"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
  </menu><div id="socialmedia">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="img/fb.png"></a> <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="img/twit.png"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <article> text </article>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">© 2014 copyright</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(../img/bga.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    background-image: url(../img/background2.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}   

#back {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(../img/background3.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#top {
    position: relative;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}
menu {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
}


#middle {
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
}

#bottom {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width: 99%;
    text-align: right;
}
logo {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}
article {
    background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.75);
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 630px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}


logo img{
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
}

.button1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Righteous', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.button2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'exo 2', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.button3 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Redressed', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.button4 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.button5 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.button6 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Patrick Hand SC', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

menu a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

menu a:hover {
    color: #5CB94C;
}
#socialmedia {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#socialmedia img{
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: relative;

}
```

CSS mobile:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#back { -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:visible;
}

#top {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    display: block;
}
menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    hight: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}


#middle {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#bottom {
    height: auto;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:3px;

}
logo {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
article {
    background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.75);
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: auto;
    width: 95%;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: none;
}


.button1 {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Righteous', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.button2 {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'exo 2', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.button3 {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Redressed', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.button4 {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.button5 {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.button6 {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Patrick Hand SC', Arial, Baveuse;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#socialmedia {
    float: none;
    width:  90%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:right;
}

#socialmedia img{
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: relative;

}

}
```

Comment: Hey, it would be useful if you just explained *what is not working* instead of just pasting all you have.

Comment: `<logo>` is not a valid HTML5 tag, `<menu>` also. Using CSS you don't have to repeat all over again your code; here I'm talking about `.buttonN` simply target all the descendants of the parent element which should rather be: `<div id="menu">` or if you really want a valid HTML5 tag than `<nav>` -> CSS: `nav > div {/*styles here*/}` and you have them all. I tried to recreate a demo with the code you posted but I'm not getting anything useful to start suggesting you: http://jsbin.com/pilaw/1/edit

Comment: Going along with what Roko said... You've got a lot of redundant code and some weird stuff in your code. I fixed your problem, it was occurring when you were trying to use `float:left;` in your "menu" tag. I changed that to a div and just made menu a class, you can also find the results here: http://jsfiddle.net/dYdM8/

Comment: yes, okay I see there's the <header> tag I should've been using instead of the none existing logo tag. And the <nav> tag instead of the non existing menu tag. And BuddhistBeast found the problem. :) changed float to none. Thank you!